# python accessing the second to the last element in a list

Tags: python, list, split

I have created a dictionary which I have assigned the first element of a list as a key.  I would like to append the rest of the elements as values to the dictionary:

file_a contains tab delimited fields.

```
a = {}
for line in file_a.readlines():
    split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
    a[split_line[0]] = []
    a[split_line[0]].append(split_line[::-1]) # append from second to last element to the list
```

The ::-1 appends all the elements.  I need to append all elements except the first one (as that is used as a key).  Any help will be appreciated.

e.g. if fields are: X\t1\t2\t3 I would like the hash to be:

```
'X': ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: `split_line[1:][::-1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python slice syntax is `alist[start:end:step]`. So, with your slice `::-1`, you are just reversing the list.
If you want the second element to the last, the correct slice would be
`alist[1:]`

```
a = {}
for line in file_a.readlines():
    split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
    a[split_line[0]] = split_line[1:]
```

Comment: why does that give me 'X': [['1', '2', '3']] with a list within a list?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {}
for line in file_a:
    split_line = line.strip().split('\t')
    a[split_line[0]] = split_line[1:]
```

You slicing expression `split_line[::-1]` evaluates to `split_line` reversed, because the third parameter is the step (-1 in this case). You want to start at element 1 and go all the way to the end, with the default step of 1. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1258041) for more on slice notation.